# How to handle Angular 1.x component URL root?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

With the intent of having a way to setup component templates' URLs root, an available config object would be needed at the iif level.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.component('myDashboard', {
        // templateUrl: HOW_TO_GET_ROOT_HERE + '/path/to/template.html'
        templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html'
    });
})();
```

So far, the only way I found this possible is to have the module object added some custom properties - but it really feels nasty to do so.

```
// define
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app._config = {root: 'http://my.cdn.js'}
//...
// use
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.component('myDashboard', {
   templateUrl: app._config.root + '/path/to/template.html'
}
```

Is there any other, more neat, approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a new constant inside angular you app module. Then utilize that common configuration inside `templateUrl` function to form `templateUrl`. Now `templateUrl` function can have injectables.

```
app.constant('config', { rootPath: 'http://my.cdn.js'});
```

**Component**

```
app.component('myDashboard', {
   templateUrl: function(config){
     return config.rootPath + '/path/to/template.html'
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, apparently one can inject even services this way - having a function with param dependencies returning component prop values.